# Where is Apple's talking robot Cocoa demo?

Tags: macos, cocoa, text-to-speech, speech

As I recall back in Mac OS X Leopard days, there is an example project that shows a talking robot with animated mouth, found very near to `NSSpeechSynthesizer`'s help topic.

Now I couldn't find that example with the documentation that comes with Xcode 4.3.1. Can somebody help point a link where I can download that sample project? (or perhaps upload it to Github if Apple no longer host it?)

Background: I need to file a Radar bug report which involves Apple's text-to-speech voices and need to upload a sample code based on their example to illustrate the bug.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think Apple is hosting it anymore, but I have some old examples from Xcode 2.5. Is [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xSlRr.png) the robot?

Comment: Actually, [Apple is still hosting that code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaSpeechSynthesisExample/Introduction/Intro.html), but you need have an idea of what it's called to find it.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw you should make this an answer.